# How to prevent loading all Tabs in Tablayout with Viewpager2 during initialization via TabLayoutMediator?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I have a `Viewpager2` set up with `Tablyout` via `TabLayoutMediator`. Adapter for the `Viewpager2` is `RecyclerView.Adapter`

I am initializing `Viewpager2` and `Tablayout`, and loading image into tabs as below:

```
    myViewPager.apply {
        offscreenPageLimit = 6
        adapter = myRecycerViewAdapter
    }

    TabLayoutMediator(myTabLayout, myViewPager) { tab, position ->
        val tabView: View =
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tab_magazine_preview, null)

         Glide.with(context)
        .load(urls[position])
        .into(tabView.imageView)

        tab.customView = tabView
    }.attach()
```

Now this implementation creates all tabs during initializing and loads all `urls` into `imageview` in tabs. This is resource consuming approach as user might not swipe to all the way till the end. And If I have huge list of urls, this is even more resource consuming.

There is nice feature of `Viewpager2` - `offscreenPageLimit` which helps to load only certain amount of adjacent pages. Can I have similar feature for Tablayout?

I want to load only ceratin amount of adjacent tabs at time as user swipes.

Comment: when you create TabLayoutMediator set smoothscroll to false

TabLayoutMediator(myTabLayout, myViewPager, autorefresh = true, smoothScroll= false)

Answer (score 1):

You can detect swipe gestures on `TabLayout` using `View.OnScrollChangeListener`
and then load images, but quick test showed me that you need to load images manually on initialization for visible tabs, because there was no scrolling.

```
tabLayout.setOnScrollChangeListener { v, scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY ->
    if (v is TabLayout) {
        val scrollBounds = Rect()
        v.getHitRect(scrollBounds)
        for (i in 0 until v.tabCount) {
            if (v.getTabAt(i)!!.view.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
                Log.i("!!!!!!!!!!", "child visible at: "  + i);
                // check if image is not loaded/loading and load
            } else {
                Log.i("!!!!!!!!!!", "child invisible: "  + i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**. I misunderstood the question:

You can do that by listening for `ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback` and telling desired fragments to load their images based on page position.

Make sure your page fragment implements interface  that allows it to load image:

```
interface ILoadImage {
    fun loadImage()
}

class MyPageFragment : Fragment(), ILoadImage {
    private var isImageLoaded = false
    
    override fun loadImage() {
        if (isImageLoaded) return
        /*
         ... load image
         */
        isImageLoaded = true
    }
}
```

Then inside your `myRecycerViewAdapter` create function that will accept selected page position and update fragments

```
class MyRecycerViewAdapter /* ... */ {
    val fragments: List<ILoadImage> = //...
    
    fun loadImagesForPosition(position: Int) {
        fragments[position].loadImage()
        // also you can load images for next or prev fragments
    }
}
```

And finally listen for `OnPageChangedCallback` and tell adapter to update fragments

```
myViewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
    override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
        super.onPageSelected(position)
        myRecycerViewAdapter.loadImagesForPosition(position)
    }
})
```

Comment: Does this method get triggered for offscreen pages too?

Comment: This callback is triggered for ViewPager2. It contains `onPageSelected(int position)` call. Using this `position` you can start loading images for desired fragments (assuming your `myRecycerViewAdapter` has easy access to list of all fragments)

Comment: I've edited my answer with some code to make it clearer

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: I tried similar approach, but It is loading data only when page is selected. If I scroll the tabs without selecting any, no data is being loaded.

Comment: You can use `onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)` instead of `onPageSelected(int position)`. Just make sure you are handling multiple calls for loading image

Comment: onPageScrolled gets called when you scroll the page itself, not the tabs

Comment: Oh, I get it! Sorry, I overlooked your code. The image is on the tab itself. I will edit my answer